# How can I parse multilines in text file using python?

Tags: python, parsing, split

I edit the sample

Here is sample textfile.txt

```
    -------!@#$-------
    text line1
    text line2
    -------!@#$-------
    dummy text dummy test dummy test
    dummy test dummy test dummy test        
    -------!@#$-------
    text line3
    text line4
    -------!@#$-------
```

I want to parse

"text line 1\n text line 2"  → array [0]

"text line 3\n text line 4"  → array [1]

How should I source coding in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) function is good for doing this:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    data = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(f_input, lambda x: not x.startswith("-------!@#$-------")) if k]
    data = [''.join(x) for x in data]

print data
```

Giving you `data` holding:

```
['text line1\ntext line2\n', 'text line3\ntext line4\n']
```

The first list comprehension reads the file grouping lines that do not start with your line separator. This results in `data` holding:

```
[['text line1\n', 'text line2\n'], ['text line3\n', 'text line4\n']]
```

Next, a second list comprehension is used to join back the multiple lines.

So:

```
data[0] --> 'text line1\ntext line2\n'
data[1] --> 'text line3\ntext line4\n'
```

---

To parse out sections containing certain words, the second list comprehension could be replaced with this one:

```
data = [''.join(x) for x in data if 'dummy test' not in ''.join(x)]
```

Comment: The time complexity i high when using this method compared to split (in built). !

Comment: May I have one more question? I edit the sample textfile

Comment: What is special about the lines you don't want? For example, are they always the 2nd entry? Or do they contain text you don't want?

Comment: Now the source code is "dummy text dummy test dummy test\n dummy text dummy test dummy test"  → array[1] I don`t want that

Comment: I have updated the script, just use something like `data = [''.join(x) for x in data if 'dummy test' not in ''.join(x)]`

Answer (score 1):

Given a file or list of strings such as:

```
>>> sample = '''\
    -------!@#$-------    # line 0 --> 0th in group --> skip
    text line1            # line 1 --> 1st in group --> save in "last"
    text line2            # line 2 --> 2nd in group --> add to "last"
    -------!@#$-------    # line 3 --> 0th in group --> skip
    text line3            # line 4 --> 1st in group --> save in "last"
    text line4            # line 5 --> 2nd in group --> add to "last"
'''.splitlines(keepends=True)
```

The easiest way to accumulate across multiple lines is to count the lines and take different actions depend on whether it is the 0th line in the group should be skipped, the 1st line in the group should be saved in a variable, or the 2nd line in the group which should be aggregated with the one saved in the variable:

```
>>> array = []
>>> last = ''
>>> for i, line in enumerate(sample):
        if i % 3 == 1:
            last = line
        elif i % 3 == 2:
            line = last + line
            array.append(line)

>>> array
['    text line1\n    text line2\n', '    text line3\n    text line4\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on your delimiter and then cleanup the individual array elements

```
sample = '''-------!@#$-------
text line1
text line2
-------!@#$-------
text line3
text line4
'''.split('-------!@#$-------')

>> ['', '\ntext line1\ntext line2\n', '\ntext line3\ntext line4\n']
```

Cleanup looks something like this

```
print [x.strip() for x in sample if len(x) > 0]

>> ['text line1\ntext line2', 'text line3\ntext line4']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a required list List of lines for given filename

```
with open('textfile.txt','r') as f:
  lines = f.read()
result=lines.split('-------!@#$-------')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split with the separator line. Then filter the non empty string in list.
With that result, strip the trailing new line.

That is,

```
with open('textfile.txt','r') as f:
    print map(str.strip,filter(None,f.read().split('-------!@#$-------')))
```

For the updated text file that has dummy contents you can use lambda function!

```
with open('textfile.txt','r') as f:
    print map(str.strip,filter(lambda i: i and 'dummy' not in i,f.read().split('-------!@#$-------')))
```

Output:

```
['text line1\ntext line2', 'text line3\ntext line4']
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: oh good! thank but My sample file has been modified, what should I do with it?

Comment: modified as in? Is that any specific text in the line taht has to be ignored or any specific pattern?